# Reading change feed from specific date/time in multiregion account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have an API where we store the configuration in a container in Cosmos DB. We are considering using the Cosmos change feed to subscribe to configuration changes using a change feed processor in order to be able to remove the configurations from cache when they are changed. We have deployments in multiple Azure regions, thus our account is multiregion write account. Now, I read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor#reading-from-a-previous-date-and-time) that

> Starting the change feed processor at a specific date and time is not supported in multi-region write accounts.

What does it mean in practice? Will the processor read and handle all changes from the beginning every time the API process is restarted? Is there any way to pass around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cosmos DB account either has 1 write region (with as many read region replicas as you want) or has all regions being both write and read regions). Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-multi-master

You can start a change feed processor with 3 different starting points:

- Now
- The beginning of the collection lifetime
- Some particular point in time

This note means that if your account has multiple write regions (instead of 1 write region), you can only start a change feed from Now or the Beginning, you cannot start a Change Feed from a specific point in time.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the change feed processor start by default from Now, which is ok for me.

Comment: Correct, that's what is covered in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor#starting-time

Comment: Yes, missed that. Thanks anyway.